# How can I conditionally run a container depending on environment in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core world, we have `appsettings.{environment}.json`, do we have similar thing in docker's world?

My scenario is, I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that starts a couple of container services. But during the integration tests, I want to start an additional container service just for integration tests. I know I can't use `.env` file to specify environment to be used in the `docker-compose.yml` file. But I don't want the specified container service to be created and started in non-integration environment, which means I don't want to start the container and overwrite the setting based on passing environemnt from `.env` file, I want `docker-compose.yml` completed ignores the container service for non-integration environments.

so is it something like `docker-compose-{environment}.yml` like `appsettings.{environment}.json` that can be merged?

Comment: Is specifying the docker compose profile a valid solution for you? so the integration test container service will only run when the profile is specified. ie `docker compose --profile dev --profile integration up -d`. [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20enable%20multiple,and%20debug%20will%20be%20enabled.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20enable,compose%20%2D%2Dprofile%20%22*%22%20.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose [Profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are used to address this.

Using an example from the linked documentation, you assign your debug container to a specific profile:

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    image: backend

  db:
    image: mysql

  tests:
    image: tests
    depends_on:
      - db
    profiles:
      - debug
```

With a `compose.yaml` structured like this, you can either start the default services by omitting the target profile, or specific services by specifying the profile name.

```bash
# Only start backend and db
$ docker compose up -d

# Starts backend and db and tests
$ docker compose up -d --profile debug
```

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose or Dockerfile does not have a mechanism to handle conditions.
there are two ways you can handle conditions in docker-related files.
first, use two different env files like `.env` and `.env.example`, and point to `.env.example` in a container that runs integration tests secondly you can use a bash file and override the environment inside the container if it runs in test mode. don't forget when you point to an environment file inside docker-compose, docker sets all environments as os environments inside the container.

Comment: the problem of this approach is, I don't want to start the container for dev, stg, prod, I only want the container starts for integration tests. If I go with your approach, the container will always starts (the configuration is different, but that doesn't matter), dev, stg, prod doesn't need the container service, only integration tests need that container service

Comment: in this case, you can use two compose files that points to same docker file
for example `docker-compose.test.yml` and `docker-compose.yml`
and the body of docker composes are the same the only difference is that `docker-compose.test.yml` points to `.env.test` file and `docker-compose.yml` points to `.env` file